# Skip through dates in DataSet with for loop nested within a foreach

Tags: c#, dataset, comparison

My goal is to trim all string datatypes within my dataset and then replace the "untrimmed" with the trimmed.

I encounter the following error:
"ArgumentException was unhandled - String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.Couldn't store <> in DateofBirth Column.  Expected type is DateTime."

when I run the following code:

```
foreach (DataRow y in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count -1; i++)
    {
        if (y[i].GetType() != typeof(DateTime))
        {
            string strTrim = y[i].ToString().Trim();
            y[i] = strTrim;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure I'm on the right track, I just can't manage to crack it :/

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Might be wrong, but with `i < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count -1` : you gonna miss one column, don't you ? Wether you do `<=` `Count-1` or `<` and `Count`

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus, I ran the code, and it still trimmed it. I'm sure the count will always be 1 higher that the index # of whatever you're referencing, hence the "-1"

Comment: Hmmm... looks strange. Well, I may miss something !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just looking for strings why are you checking for `DateTime`?  Try:

```
if (y[i] is string)
{
    y[i] = ((string)y[i]).Trim();
}
```

Comment: @D Stanley. Thanks! Worked beautifully.